# How to change button position go down (constraint layout) in kotlin android ? I need space to display a message once the button is clicked

Tags: android, kotlin

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/heartRateButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:text="@string/heartRate_button"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/midnight_blue"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.647"
```

So basically what I want to change is the app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.647". But I need to be able to change it in the mainActivity.kt file instead of in the XML file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these lines of code to set vertical bias programmatically

```
//id of the button
val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.heartRateButton)


val newParam:ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams = 
            (button.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams)
newParam.verticalBias = 1.0f
        
button.layoutParams = newParam
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of moving the Button yourself, you might want to place the message TextView in the layout where the Button is now, and constrain the Button to sit below it

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/some_message"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.647"
/>

<Button
        android:id="@+id/heartRateButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:text="@string/heartRate_button"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/midnight_blue"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_goneMarginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="message"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
/>
```

So the `message` box is displayed where the `Button` was, and the `Button` is constrained below it with a top margin set. But there's also the `layout_goneMarginTop` attribute, which gives it a different margin when the thing it's constrained to has `GONE` for its visibility.

So basically, when the message box is set to `GONE`, it takes up no space in the layout, and the button moves up to where the message box would be, with no margin. When the message box is set to `VISIBLE`, it appears, and the button slides down below it, and applies a top margin to give it some space between the two. You just have to hide or show the message box in code by setting its visibility, the constraints do the rest!

---

If the message box isn't supposed to be exactly where the button is, you could try something with a `Barrier` constrained to the bottom of `message` and maybe a `Guideline` (or an empty `View`) where the Button should be. Set it so the barrier is pushed down to the lower of those two things, and constrain your button to that. That way, if the message box isn't visible, the Guideline or whatever is lower, and the Button fixes to that. If the message becomes visible, it pushes the barrier lower and moves the button down where it needs to be